Formula to sum a specific property for all items in array on Notion
How can I sum all the properties with name "quantity" on a Formula property column when selecting an array.
Let me explain with an example:

First DB:


Second DB:



I just want to add 6 and 4 in the first DB into the column "Formula" of the second DB but I don't know how to sum all the properties "Quantity" of each entry of the first DB. I can access the first or last item of the first DB with prop("Relation A").first().prop("Quantity") which gives 6.  prop("Relation A") returns an array.
But, how can I iterate over all the items in DB A to get both?
Thank you

The correct formula would be prop("Relation A").map(current.prop("Quantity").sum(). The .map() function applies the expression written within it to each item in the array it's called for, creating a new array made up of the results. To make this clearer:
prop("Relation A") /* Gets each Relation A value */
.map(current.prop("Quantity") /* Gets each Quantity value for each Relation A value */
.sum() /* Adds the Quantity values together */

